# SignalR Validate WinForm Client Integrity

Tags: signalr

From the SignalR hub, i want to enforce the connecting client is the WinForm program I distributed. Is there a way to "challenge" the client from the hub, by asking for a secret, or code signing certificate, or checksum of the exe, or anything?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR connection does not intended for such purposes - it just connects to a service hub. You can always challenge a user on WinForm side before connection run

```
if (secretValue == inputSecret) {
   await hubConnection.Start();
} else {
   // notify user that secret is incorrect
}
```